# Identify application when sharing something from charm in windows 8 store application c#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I am developing windows store application using C# XAML and using windows store charm to share my content.

is there any way to identify that from which application my content was shared?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can't, the idea is to have sandboxed applications that don't know about each other. You register them as share sources or targets and then a broker handles the interaction between them so there is never any direct contact.

[image]

Looking at the available members on the objects used for the implementation I can't see anything that would provide information about where the share was made from.

Provide some information about what you want to achieve.